# Training input images and noisy images in autoencoder providing poor results

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have two datasets one is original image and other is noisy dataset and I am applying autoencoder to produce an image but the reconstructed image is quite bad can you see what could be the potential issue and accuracy is 0.0000 as well below is my code for model.fit()
please let me know if any other information is required.

```
input_size=x_train.shape[1]
hidden_size=128
code_size=32

input_img=tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_size,))

hidden_1=layers.Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu') (input_img)

code=layers.Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_1)

hidden_2=layers.Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(code)

output_img=layers.Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_2)

autoencoder=tf.keras.Model(input_img, output_img)

import h5py
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
filepath='C:/Users/Documents/Dataset/Smallest Dataset/CheckPoints-FLAIR/weights-improvement-{epoch:2d}-{binary_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5'
checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='binary_accuracy', verbose=1, mode='max')

csvLogger = keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('C:/Users/Documents/Dataset/Smallest Dataset/CheckPoints-FLAIR/FLAIR.csv')
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SpecificityAtSensitivity(0,1),tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(0,1),'binary_accuracy','accuracy'])

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train_noisy, 
                shuffle=True,
                callbacks=[csvLogger,checkpoint],
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test_noisy),
                epochs=5)
```

Comment: send your model or model.summary(), with model.fit() we can not help you

Comment: check again please.

Comment: This model is not correct for autoencoder. Do you train your encoder-decoder correctly?

Comment: Through above method I am training only.

Comment: So, You are doing wrong, What do you want exactly? Do you want an encode-decoder? Or do you want an approach for increasing the quality of images?

Comment: encoder-decoder

Comment: read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder), for encoder-decoder first you need to train the full model (encoder-decoder) then split model as encoder & decoder. with an encoder, you can encode features and with a decoder, you can use features and get original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your autoencoder architecture is wrong that is why the accuracy is poor as it is not encoding and decoding correctly.